# when to choose java over scala in mixed scala/java projects

Tags: java, scala

Context: I am a novice to JVM and trying to build an app using Scala.

I was wondering, in mixed language projects (Scala/Java), for example Apache Spark, Apache Kafka, when do people choose to use Java to write a module where they already have been using Scala so far to write other modules, i.e. why those parts are not written in Scala itself?

Basically what are some example scenarios?

Answer (score 3):

1. If for whatever reason you need to define a native java enum. Scala 2 has no syntax for defining them.
2. If you need an API that can be used by java programmers and you want to guarantee that not a single Scala specific feature or compilation artifact (mangled names, `MODULE$` fields on objects ...) leaks out.